# Difference in meaning between words in a context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, difference, word-difference

- 1) It triggered a process that we are now trying to end.
- 2) It started off a process that we are now trying to end.
- 3) It toggled a process that we are now trying to end.
- 4) It activated a process that we are now trying to end.
- 5) It started a process that we are now trying to end.

Which are correct and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Started" (#2, #5) and "triggered" (#1) are best, "activated" (#4) sounds less emphatic and more chemically oriented, "toggled" (#3) usually implies the process can be toggled back easily which contradicts the rest of the sentence since "now trying to end" implies difficulty in ending it.

Comment: Between "triggered" and "started/started off" is there a difference? Does the preposition "off" add anything up to the word "started"?

Comment: I think #5 is much better than #2. Indeed, _started off_ can be used as a phrasal verb, but it doesn’t work very well in this context.

Comment: #5 is the usual way of saying this, "off" in #2 is redundant.  Saying it "started" a process sounds like a more direct linkage than "triggered", for example one ["starts the ball rolling"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/start+the+ball+rolling) but doesn't "trigger the ball to roll".